# Creating an instance of a View Controller without loosing the objects in the Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

All,

I am trying to set a computed value in a view controller from a different class. Within this computed value it sets a value on an object (Bar Button Item). Like so :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var BarButtonPAY: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var PAYLABEL: UILabel!

    var initalvalue : Int
    var PayButton : Int   {
        didSet {
            BarButtonPAY.enabled = true
        }
    }
```

In another class, I am trying to set up a connection to the view controller so I can change the value of the computed property. When i set it up like this :

```
var myCustomViewController: ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
myCustomViewController.PayButton = 1
```

it clears the view hierarchy and makes PayButton an optional - because it has been cleared out.

and if i use :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! UIViewController
```

to connect to the view controller (after reading - this should not wipe out the view hierarchy), then I cannot get my value so

```
viewController.PayButton
```

is not there... 
Can anyone please advise ?

Comment: do you actually *want* to create a *new instance* of the ViewController? Or are you actually trying to *access* an *existing one*?

Comment: Access the existing one, so I can amend a computed property on it from another class.

Comment: Then both of the solutions you currently tried are very wrong because both *create new instances* as the name "instantiateViewController" for example suggests. From where do you try to access the Controller, how are the two controllers related, what is the view hierarchy?

Comment: I want to access the view controller properties from another class. The other class is a tableviewcell, because there is a button on each cell and that button needs to highlight the bar button (which is sitting in the view controller). The reason for this is because the cell is overriden and there is a container view in my view controller which holds the tableviewcontroller.

Comment: What you should probably do is the following: give each cell a reference to the ViewController they should change the property on. That reference-giving should probably happen in cellForRowAtIndexPath or something along those lines. That is the fast way - the prettier way would be to setup a delegate. I guess the containerView nows its parent? if not, that knowledge is not to hard to come by. Is the containerViewController the datasource for the tableView or is there another layer in between?